# Allow comma after at least one number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a regular expression allow comma after a number. i have tried But after number it allowing commas `122,,,`

I want:

`12,323,232,2,232
1,1,1,1,1
123123,23231,2322`


I don;t want:


`12312,,,123,,2,32,
12312,123,12,,,,,123,12`

My code is

```
$(".experience").keyup(function (e) { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\{0,9}]/g,''); 
});
```

Comment: You forgot to paste the regex.

Comment: You don't want `,2` as well (*starting* comma), do you?

Comment: Yes, after number i don't want 2 or more commas

Comment: <code>here is my code: $(".experience").keyup(function (e) { this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\{0,9}]/g,''); });</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to **remove any commas not succeeding a number**, and also **remove any characters other than digits or commas**. This is fairly simple if your language supported lookbehinds, however it isn't that hard in javascript too. You could use the below regex to match any incorrect commas and then replace them with `$1`

```
/^,+|(,)+|[^0-9,]+/g
```

Replace With: `$1`

- Any commas at the start should be replaced with an empty string `''`
- Any commas which are consecutive i.e `,+`, they should be replaced by a single comma i.e `,`
- Any characters other than digits or comma should be replaced with an empty string `''`

To combine these two rules, `^,+|(,)+` will help match both and the replace `$1` corresponds to capturing group 1, which will only be present in the 2nd condition so it will replace multiple commas with a single comma i.e `(,)+` is replaced with `(,)`. Whereas in the first alternative `^,+` which matches commas at the starting, there is the first capturing group remains empty so it gets replace with empty string `''`

Here's a js demo:

```js
$(function() {
   $(".experience").keyup(function (e) {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/^,+|(,)+|[^0-9,]+/g,'$1');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='experience' name="experience" value=""/>
```

You could consider changing `keyup` to `focusout` instead, although it's upto you! :)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1N7zVc/3)

Comment: `^\d+(?:,\d+)*$` is better. But this won't work. OP uses it in the `replace` function on the `keyup` event.

Comment: Thank you but i applied this solution jquery [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/4PuJL/741/)  keyup but it is not working

Comment: not working means allowing to commas after number like (1232,,,,123,,,)

Comment: You aren't using the regex correctly. I'm not sure how you want the input box to behave. What are you expecting the `.replace()` function to do?

Comment: Thanks @degant exact solution but i don't to allow characters and special characters also

Comment: Just add another alternative `[^0-9,]+`. Updated the answer

Comment: Perfect..! @degant Working as expected...:)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I'm not used to working with regex's, but managed to quickly put this together:

```
^([0-9]+\,?)*$

The questionmark is makes the comma optional.
[0-9] = numeric values only
+     = quantifier between 1 and unlimited
\     = escapes the character, so it's a constant
*     = quantifier between 0 and unlimited times
```

Hope this helps!

Regards